# Adding shapefiles to specific .mxd project using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, layers

I am new to automating geoprocesses.

In ModelBuilder, I conducted a geoprocess of transforming some points in excel to a shapefile, and then to make a buffer of 4 kms to these.

As a result, two shapefiles are produced, like the ones I mentioned above.

I leave you a screenshot :

[image]

In the same ModelBuilder, is there a way to automatically add these two shapefiles to a given .mxd project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you're running the tool *as a tool* (not from the Model window), you need to make model parameters. If something is a parameter, the default geoprocessing environment is set to add those outputs to your map. Note - you cannot add the result to an MXD other than the one you're in. To do that, you'll need to write a Python script, make that into a tool and add that as a sub-tool to your model.

In short:

- Expose the outputs as parameters
- Run the tool from the toolbox (not model window)
- Make sure your geoprocessing environment setting adds output to the map

[Read more about model parameters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm)

Comment: Exactly, what I need is to make a script and turn it into a tool and later as a sub-tool to the model.

Is this script done arcpy or at a generic python level?
Any reference to do it?